# How can I return a stream in a WCF response asynchronously from a task?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous-wcf-call

I have a class that does some long-running processing with lots of data and writes the output to a stream that I provide. I am trying to put a WCF front on this (using named pipes) but having trouble figuring out how to return the stream. I have something like this so far:

```
interface IProcessor { Stream GetStream(); }

class Host {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Processor), new Uri[]{new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")})) {
      var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
      binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse;
      sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IProcessor), binding, "foo");
      sh.Open();
      Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
      Console.ReadLine();
      sh.Close();
    }
  }
}

class Processor : IProcessor {
  Stream GetStream() {
    var SourceProcessor = new SourceProcessor(...);
    var s = new MemoryStream();
    new Task(() => { SourceProcessor.Run(s); }).Start();
    return s;
  }
}

class Client {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
    var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
    binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse;
    ChannelFactory<IProcessor> f = new ChannelFactory<IProcessor>(binding, new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/foo"));
    Console.WriteLine("Creating channel...");
    IProcessor eps = f.CreateChannel();
    Console.WriteLine("Getting stream.");
    Stream s = eps.GetStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
    while (!sr.EndOfStream) Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Everything goes through the motions but of course none of the source data makes it through to the client. I'm confused as to how I can do this (maybe I can't) since I need to both return the stream and run the task and potentially wait for the task to finish. If I just call SourceProcessor.Run(s) without being in a task, it would block and buffer, allegedly, but I'm not sure how to make it wait until the task is done while also returning the stream for the client to read...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is WCF will think it the stream is "done" if it calls `Read(` and the call returns 0 bytes. `MemoryStream` will happily do that, it will not block reads if there is no data available.

The source of your problem is WCF is reading the `MemoryStream` faster than you are writing to it and thinking it is "done", the way to fix it is you will need to return a different type of `Stream` that blocks instead of returning 0 when there is no data available. There is nothing built in to .NET that will do this, you will need to either find a 3rd party class or make your own (it may be as simple as derive from MemoryStream and override `Read` to block reads until a "Done" flag is set (See [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) and its [`CompleteAdding()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086(v=vs.110).aspx) method for a similar behavior)).

For fun I threw this together, it is totally untested but it might do what you need.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;

namespace Example
{
    public class BufferStream : Stream
    {
        public BufferStream()
        {
            _data = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();
        }


        /// <param name="boundedCapacity">The maximum number of calls to <see cref="Write"/> that can be made without
        /// the buffer being drained.</param>
        public BufferStream(int boundedCapacity)
        {
            _data = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>(boundedCapacity);
        }

        private readonly BlockingCollection<byte[]> _data;
        private byte[] _currentBlock = null;
        private int _currentBlockIndex = 0;

        public int BoundedCapacity { get { return _data.BoundedCapacity; } }

        public int BufferedWrites { get { return _data.Count; } }

        public bool IsAddingCompleted
        {
            get { return _data.IsAddingCompleted; }
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return _data.IsCompleted; }
        }

        public void CompleteAdding()
        {
            _data.CompleteAdding();
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            var localArray = new byte[count];

            //Copy the data in to a new buffer of exactly the count size.
            Array.Copy(buffer, offset, localArray, 0, count);

            _data.Add(localArray);
        }


        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            if (_currentBlock == null || _currentBlockIndex == _currentBlock.Length)
            {
                if (!GetNextBlock()) 
                    return 0;
            }

            int minCount = Math.Min(count, _currentBlock.Length - _currentBlockIndex);

            Array.Copy(_currentBlock, _currentBlockIndex, buffer, offset, minCount);
            _currentBlockIndex += minCount;

            return minCount;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the next block in to <see cref="_currentBlock"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True if the next block was retrieved.</returns>
        private bool GetNextBlock()
        {
            if (!_data.TryTake(out _currentBlock))
            {
                //The TryTake failed, the collection is empty.

                //See if we are in the completed state.
                if (_data.IsCompleted)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                //Wait for more data to show up.
                try
                {
                    _currentBlock = _data.Take();
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    //If the blocking collection was marked complete while we where waiting Take throws a InvalidOperationException
                    return false;
                }
            }

            _currentBlockIndex = 0;
            return true;
        }

        #region Constant functions

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override bool CanSeek
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override long Length
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }

        public override long Position
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
            set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The advantage of this over deriving from `MemoryStream` is once a value has been read by WCF it no longer needs to remain in memory (the entire point of returning a `Stream` instead of a `byte[]`)

Comment: I'm using your class to stream data via a WCF Streamed TCP service and it's been working great so far. Thanks!

Comment: I also used this class to enable "forwarding" a WCF backend stream to a client connected to a middle broker. The backend returned a stream to the broker, and the broker was trying to return the same stream to the client, and unfortunately there were synchronization conflicts _('the read method cannot be called when another read operation is pending')_. Wrapping the WCF stream received by the broker with this class and returning the wrapped instance to the client solved the issue.  Nice one Scott!!! +1